# Arrange different heights divs on three symmetric columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I've created a custom page template for WordPress that display in the content area the categories, subcategories and posts in the following manner:

```
<div class="categories">
    <span class="categoryName">Category #1</span>
    <ul>
        <li class="subcategories">
            <span class="subcategoryName">Subcategory #1</span>
            <div class="posts">
                <span class="postName">
                    <a href="">Post #1</a>
                </span>
                <span class="postName">
                    <a href="">Post #2</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="subcategories">
            <span class="subcategoryName">Subcategory #2</span>
            <div class="posts">
                <span class="postName">
                    <a href="">Post #3</a>
                </span>
                <span class="postName">
                    <a href="">Post #4</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The posts are shown only when the user clicks on the subcategory and hidden when the subcategory is clicked again:

```
jQuery(".subcategories").on("click", function() {
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass("hidePosts")) {
        jQuery(this).children("div").hide();
        jQuery(this).removeClass("hidePosts");
    } else {
        jQuery(this).children("div").show();
        jQuery(this).addClass("hidePosts");
    }
});
```

The issue that I have and I couldn't figure it out it is regarding how the categories divs are shown. They have different heights based on the number of subcategories. Also when the posts for a specific subcategory are displayed the height becomes bigger. I arrange them in three columns like following:

```
.categories {
    float: left;
    width: 46%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
```

The problem could be clearly spotted in the printscreen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhO7h.jpg .
I've tried to set a minimum height based on the biggest category but it's still looking chaotic when I display the posts because of the height that becomes bigger. Also I've tried with jQuery to calculate the previous and next category divs height when the user clicks on a subcategory and add a bigger padding so that all the beneath category divs to be still on the same line but with no success. I can't figure it out what do try now so any guidance is more than welcomed. I hope I've explain myself clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a clear fix after every third block, this will prevent your layout dripping as you've shown in your screenshot.

Worth a read http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work but it helps me to figure it out. I've add a class every three divs starting with the first one (jQuery). The class was set the clear to both. Thank you for you guidance